# Why does std::find_if used on std::istream_iterators seem to return the last element?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, input-iterator

I am learning C++ through Accelerated C++ by Andrew Koenig and Barbara E. Moo. I am trying to understand how input operators work and their relation to STL algorithms.

Here is the piece of code that confuses me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool space(char c)
{
    return std::isspace(c);
}

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<char> i = std::find_if(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        space);
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine but when I run it on any input what it outputs is the last character entered. For example, I expected the output of `123 456` to be   but it actually is 6. Similarly, I expected the output of `123456` to be some error because we try to access an element that doesn't exist, yet the output is again . What am I missing?

Comment: `std::istream_iterator` is an input iterator. For some unclear reason, only the overloads that take an execution policy parameter are specified, according to cppreference.com, as requiring forward iterators. Without an execution policy parameter, `find_if` requires only input iterators. The example in this question proves this to be an obvious defect, in my eyes. `std::find_if` should require forward iterators, not input iterators.

Comment: [It seems you can use `istream_iterator<int>()` for similar tasks.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator#Example)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- I don't know if you're right that `std::find_if` should always require at least a forward iterator, but the reason that the execution policy version requires a forward iterator is that **all** algorithms that take an execution policy require forward iterators or better. Applying a parallel algorithm to a sequence designated by an input iterator just won't work; the algorithm would have to fall back on the serial version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't `123 456` as input produce  as output?

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

> **When reading characters, std::istream_iterator skips whitespace by default** (unless disabled with std::noskipws or equivalent), while std::istreambuf_iterator does not.

Switching to `std::istreambuf_iterator` gives the desired behaviour: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RRt8kvyqyvbO1p8m

---

> Why doesn't `123456` as input produce an error?

If there is no space in the input, `find_if` will return its 2nd argument, which is the *end-of-stream* iterator.

Dereferencing the end-of-stream iterator is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which is not guaranteed to produce an error. In fact it doesn't guarantee anything, which means your program might just print the last character in your input.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you why your output is 0 though? On my machine it is blank as expected. Is this an implementation-dependent thing? Also, since std::istream_iterator skips whitespace, shouldn't my version just produce an error or whatever dereferencing an out-of-range iterator gives?

Comment: The 0 is not the output but the value returned from `main()`. If you select the output, you can see that there's a line with a single space between Start and 0. Dereferencing a past-the-end iterator is _undefined behaviour_, which means that your program no longer behaves reasonably. And in its unreasonableness, it might just print the last character in your input; or it might crash; or do something else entirely.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the detailed explanation!